# error TS2339: Property 'x' does not exist on type 'y[]

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Please give a solution for this. My `AuthorApi` interface has: `total`, `per_page`, `data` but I can't access it on the `list` component.

Why is the error showing? And, what does it mean? I can't understand what it.

**In my Author.model.ts**

```js
export interface AuthorApi {
  data: Author[];
  total: number;
  per_page: number;
}

export interface Author {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  qualification: string;
}
```

**In my author.serviece.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class AuthorService {
  url = "http://localhost:8000";

  constructor(http: HttpClient) {}

  getAuthors() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/api/Author`);
  }

  getAuthorsByPage(page: number) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/api/Author?page=${page + 1}`);
  }

  getAuthorById(id) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/api/Author/${id}`);
  }

  addAuthor(name, email, qualification) {
    const author = {
      name: name,
      email: email,
      qualification: qualification
    };

    return this.http.post(`${this.url}/api/Author`, author, {
      responseType: "json"
    });
  }

  updateAuthor(id, name, email, qualifiation) {
    const author = {
      name: name,
      email: email,
      qualifiation: qualifiation
    };

    return this.http.put(`${this.url}/api/Author/${id}`, author, {
      responseType: "json"
    });
  }

  deleteAuthor(id) {
    return this.http.delete(`${this.url}/api/Author/${id}`, {
      responseType: "json"
    });
  }

  // getAuthorsByUrl(uri: string){
  //   return this.http.get(`${uri}`);
  // }
}
```

**In my list.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";

import {
  MatSnackBar,
  MatPaginator,
  MatTableDataSource,
  MatSort
} from "@angular/material";

import { Author, AuthorApi } from "../../Module/author.model";
import { AuthorService } from "../../Shared/author.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-list",
  templateUrl: "./list.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./list.component.css"]
})
export class ListComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  authors: Author[];

  authorsApi: AuthorApi[];

  resultsLength = 0;
  perPage = 0;
  isLoadingResults = true;
  isRateLimitReached = false;

  displayedColumns = [
    "Id",
    "name",
    "email",
    "qualification",
    "created_at",
    "actions"
  ];

  constructor(authorService: AuthorService, snackbar: MatSnackBar) {}

  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: false }) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: false }) paginator: MatPaginator;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.getAuthors();
    // this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => this.paginator.pageIndex = 0);
  }

  getAuthors() {
    console.log("Getting Data...");
    this.isLoadingResults = true;
    this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => (this.paginator.pageIndex = 0));

    this.authorService
      .getAuthorsByPage(this.paginator.pageIndex)
      .subscribe((data: AuthorApi[]) => {
        this.authorsApi = data;
        this.resultsLength = data.total;
        this.perPage = data.per_page;
        this.authors = data.data;
        this.isLoadingResults = false;
        console.log(data);
        console.log(this.authorsApi);
      });
  }

  deleteAuthor(id) {
    this.authorService.deleteAuthor(id).subscribe(() => {
      this.snackbar.open("Author Has Deleted Successfully !", "OK", {
        duration: 5000
      });
      this.getAuthors();
    });
  }
}
```

My Programme is running but this error is showing up

```
ERROR in 

    src/app/Author/list/list.component.ts(51,35): error TS2339: Property 'total' does not exist on type 'AuthorApi[]'.

    src/app/Author/list/list.component.ts(52,29): error TS2339: Property 'per_page' does not exist on type 'AuthorApi[]'.

    src/app/Author/list/list.component.ts(53,29): error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'AuthorApi[]'.
```

Comment: You are trying to access to a property in an array. Try by changing `.subscribe((data: AuthorApi[]) => {` with `.subscribe((data: AuthorApi) => {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is of type `AuthorApi[]` i.e. an array of `AuthorApi`. While the properties you use exist on `AuthorApi` they **do not** exist on an array. I reckon you have typed the data wrong, it should be just `AuthorApi`. Try logging it out and see what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

For these lines `data` is an array of `AuthorApi`, but you are trying to access properties that exist in the interface of `AuthorApi`.

```
.subscribe((data: AuthorApi[]) => {
  ... 
  this.resultsLength = data.total;
  this.perPage = data.per_page;
  this.authors = data.data;
}
```

You will have to make other adjustments, but if the data returned is an array then you will most likely have to iterate through the results to get those properties like you want them.